# AttributeError on current_user.is_authenticated()

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask-Login and I want to check if a user is logged-in by calling current_user.is_authenticated().

My Flask application is organized into Blueprints with a main `__init__.py` file that sets up my app, sets up Blueprints, and initializes Flask-Login. I have a script, `run.py`, located up one directory from `__init__.py` that instantiates the application and runs it if in debug mode.

`__init.py__` looks (in part) like this:

```
from flask import Flask, session, request, render_template                                                            
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, current_user

from panel.views import dash, projects

from panel.users.models import User, AnonymousUser

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("configure") 

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "/signin"
login_manager.anonymous_user = AnonymousUser
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(str_id):
    return User.user_loader(str_id)

# Register all blueprints here.
app.register_blueprint(dash.bp, url_prefix="/dash")
app.register_blueprint(projects.bp, url_prefix="/projects")

logging.warning(current_user.is_authenticated())
```

When I run this, from `run.py` (which looks, in part, like this):

```
from panel import app 

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

This Exception is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
    from panel import app
  File "/opt/www/panel/panel/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    logging.warning(current_user.is_authenticated())
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/coefficient/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line     336, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/coefficient/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 295, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/coefficient/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 403, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _request_ctx_stack.top.user)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Because I omitted some lines for brevity, the line numbers in that traceback do not match the code I posted, but you can see that the line `logging.warning(current_user.is_authenticated())` seems to be where the error occurs.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're not inside a request so there is no current user?

Comment: @agf you're probably correct. I'll try this and post a follow-up.

Comment: Try to execute logging.warning(current_user.is_authenticated()) after app.run() (I mean in some blueprint method or the code which is callable). I think request could be created after app is running and getting the request.

Comment: @agf I'm calling current_user.is_authenticated() in a decorator in one of my files, and I can't control when the request context is set up. Because it's a decorator, it must be executing (I assume) after the app is instantiated, but before run() is called.

Comment: @skyler Even after `run` is called, there won't be a current request outside of a method.

Comment: @agf As you suspected, the problem was that I was not within a request context. If you'll add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't call

```
current_user.is_authenticated()
```

outside of a method/view, because the code outside of the methods/views will be run outside of a request.

If you're not in a request, there is no `current_user` on which to check authentication.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

[Flask-Login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuring-your-application)