# Flask-Admin different forms and column_list for different roles

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Following up on this question [Flask-Admin Role Based Access - Modify access based on role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213748/flask-admin-role-based-access-modify-access-based-on-role#36239787) I don't understand how to implement role-based views, especially regarding the form and column_lists.

Say I want `MyModelView` to show different columns if the user is a regular user or a superuser.

Overriding `is_accessible` in `MyModelView` has no effect at all

```
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, current_user

class MyModelView(SafeModelView):

    # ...

    def is_accessible(self):
        if current_user.has_role('superuser'):
            self.column_list = superuser_colum_list
            self.form_columns = superuser_form_columns
        else:
            self.column_list = user_colum_list
            self.form_columns = user_form_columns
        return super(MyModelView, self).is_accessible()

    # Has same effect as 

    def is_accessible(self):
        return super(MyModelView, self).is_accessible()
```

and defining conditional class attributes does not work either as `current_user` is not defined (`NoneType` error as per [AttributeError on current_user.is_authenticated()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710036/attributeerror-on-current-user-is-authenticated)). Doing the same in the ModelView's `__init__` being equivalent, `current_user` is still not defined

```
class MyModelView(SafeModelView):

    #[stuff]

    if current_user.has_role('superuser'):
            column_list = superuser_colum_list
            form_columns = superuser_form_columns
    else:
        column_list = user_colum_list
        form_columns = user_form_columns

    #[other stuff]
```

FYI, `SafeModelView` can be any class inheriting from `dgBaseView` in the previously mentioned question.

Comment: Why is current_user not defined? are you not using flask_login?

Comment: Not flask-login directly, updated post with import

Comment: current_user does not exist outside of a request (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710036/attributeerror-on-current-user-is-authenticated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually define view class attributes such as `column_list` as properties. It allows you to add some dynamic logic to them:

```
from flask import has_app_context
from flask_security import current_user

class MyModelView(SafeModelView):
    @property
    def column_list(self):
        if has_app_context() and current_user.has_role('superuser'):
            return superuser_column_list
        return user_column_list

    @property
    def _list_columns(self):
        return self.get_list_columns()

    @_list_columns.setter
    def _list_columns(self, value):
        pass
```

The problem with using this approach (and why your reassigning of `column_list` values in `is_accessible` function took no effect) is that many view attributes are cached on application launch and stored in private attributes. `column_list` for example is cached in `_list_columns` attribute so you need to redefine it as well. You can look how this caching works in [flask_admin.model.base.BaseModelView._refresh_cache](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L876) method.

Flask `has_app_context` method is needed here because first `column_list` read is happened on application launch when your `current_user` variable has no meaningful value yet.

The same can be done with `form_columns` attribute. The properties will look like this:

```
@property
def form_columns(self):
    if has_app_context() and current_user.has_role('superuser'):
        return superuser_form_columns
    return user_form_columns

@property
def _create_form_class(self):
    return self.get_create_form()

@_create_form_class.setter
def _create_form_class(self, value)
    pass

@property
def _edit_form_class(self):
    return self.get_edit_form()

@_edit_form_class.setter
def _edit_form_class(self, value):
    pass
```